# Call function in another class from Win32 wrapper WndProc

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a win32 wrapper class with a functioning WndProc (i use a static wndproc to forward messages to the WndProc member function).

I also have another app class which creates an instance of my win32 wrapper class.

I want the user of the app class to be able to write their own functions that represent events, such as OnMouseClick(), or OnMouseMove(), but in order for this to work, I need to call the event functions from the win32 wrapper class's Wndproc (which has no knowledge of the app class).

What's the best way to do this? Should I send a pointer to each event function to my win32 wrapper class, and call it via pointer? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Standard feature of Windows, it is called "subclassing a window".  Type that in a google query and take the first hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your classes and their purpose is not clear. Nevertheless, the typical recommnded structure of wrapper classes is the following:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void OnMouseClick(...) { }   // Empty body
    virtual void OnMouseMove(...) { }   // Empty body
};

class AppClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void OnMouseClick(...) { AppCode }
    void OnMouseMove(...) { AppCode }
};
```

Base class is calling virtual methods when it receives Windows events in its static WndProc handler. And this triggers execution of the app code.

Comment: I understand this, and this is part of my project. However, I'm asking how to deal with a separate win32 wrapper class called D3DWindow, but is instantiated within BaseClass. D3DWindow has no knowledge of OnMouseclick/OnMouseMove(), and I'm asking for a good way to make this work.

Comment: Then you better explain what you need.